# I get this error "Active: failed " from the Process: 9666 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=2)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, apache-2.4, start

I was check my web server in apache2 and when I run the next command I get this error:

```
   root@me:~# sudo systemctl status apache2
sudo: unable to resolve host me
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-07-10 16:08:46 EDT; 20min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9666 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=2)
```

Jul 10 16:08:46 me systemd[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04): Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Jul 10 16:08:46 me apache2[9666]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 46: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
Jul 10 16:08:46 me apache2[9666]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 57: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
Jul 10 16:08:47 me apache2[9666]: ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined in /etc/apache2/envvars
Jul 10 16:08:46 me systemd[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04): apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
Jul 10 16:08:46 me systemd[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04): Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jul 10 16:08:46 me systemd[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04): apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 10 16:08:46 me systemd[1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04): apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
root@me:~# 

I run this command :

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

I saw this two part from request:

```
Jul 10 16:08:46 me systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

and

```
Jul 10 16:08:47 me apache2[9666]: ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined in /etc/apache2/envvars
```

my question are why I have this error and are they something bad for me server , because I have two client in this server?

my version for me apache and linux:

```
root@me:~# apache2 -v
```

Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-06-07T19:43:03
root@me:~#

and

```
Linux me 4.15.0-24-generic #26~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 15 14:35:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

root@m

I am beginner in apache2

from this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **first** error message returned from your systemctl command is:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host me
```

As stated by roaima, the use of sudo is pointless, because you're already root and have all neccessary access rights as such. The sudo command can be used to acquire root rights, while you're logged in as an user.

The **second** error message returned from your systemctl command is:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2: 46: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
```

The /etc/apache2/envvars file is not available or you should provide access to it. Please check if the file is available first with the ls -l command. If the file exists, you should probably use the chown or chmod command to provide access.

The same question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409046/apache-pid-file-needs-to-be-defined-cant-restart-apache) on stackoverflow
. You can find further instructions to create an initial apache envvars configuration file by following the link.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the use of `sudo` is totally pointless in the OP's command set, because they are already root.